# sqlite3.OperationalError: When trying to connect to S3 Airflow Hook

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, hook

I'm currently exploring implementing hooks in some of my DAGs. For instance, in one dag, I'm trying to connect to s3 to send a csv file to a bucket, which then gets copied to a redshift table.

I have a custom module written which I import to run this process. I am trying to currently set up an S3Hook to undergo this process instead. But I'm a little confused in setting up the connection, and how everything works.

First, I input the hook

```
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
```

Then I try to make the hook instance

```
    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws-s3')
```

Next I try to set up the client

```
    s3_client = s3_hook.get_conn()
```

However when I run the client line above, I received this error

```
    OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) 
    no such table: connection
[SQL: SELECT connection.password AS connection_password, connection.extra AS connection_extra, connection.id AS connection_id, connection.conn_id AS connection_conn_id, connection.conn_type AS connection_conn_type, connection.description AS connection_description, connection.host AS connection_host, connection.schema AS connection_schema, connection.login AS connection_login, connection.port AS connection_port, connection.is_encrypted AS connection_is_encrypted, connection.is_extra_encrypted AS connection_is_extra_encrypted 
FROM connection 
WHERE connection.conn_id = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('aws-s3', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I'm trying to diagnose the error, but the tracebook is long. I'm a little confused on why sqlite3 is involved here, when I'm trying to utilize s3 here. Can anyone unpack this? Why is this error being thrown when trying to set up the client?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you just did pip install airflow and start to work but you didn't really did a setup to the application? (e.g ran airflow init db and started the scheduler + webserver)

Comment: So, I have a local webserver running, containerized in docker. I'm trying not to step on any toes here, because I don't want to run `airflow init db` on my local machine, and have it conflict with my company's production server. But my instincts tell me this is the cause for that.

Comment: airflow init db is what creates the tables in the backend. If you don't create the tables then you Airflow can't run and as you see it complains about missing tables. If you have airflow in docker then you need your dags to be in that docker too...

Comment: I see, right now I have a dag on my local machine. It's not existing in the docker environment right now, just my local machine. Maybe I should move it to that dags folder(the docker folder), and then try running the code? By running, I mean running line by line in Spyder. For some context, I'm running line by line just see how hooks function.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is not just a library - it's also an application.
To execute Airflow code you must have airflow instance running this mean also having a database with the needed schema.

To create the tables you must execute `airflow init db`.

**Edit:**
After the discussion in comments. Your issue is that you have working Airflow application inside docker but your DAGs are written on your local disk. Docker is closed environment if you want Airflow to recognize your dags you must move the files to the DAG folder in the docker.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to me. However.. what I'm trying to do is test out the code. Run it line by line so to speak, so understand how hooks work. So when I run the line of code in the dag that's located in the DAG folder inside docker, I still receive this error. It's not like in this situation, I'm trying to run the DAG locally, just yet. Does that make sense? Maybe, within the docker environment, I need to run `airflow initdb`

Comment: To test the code use unit tests: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#unit-tests

Comment: See, I'm not trying to test the DAG here, though. I'm trying to set up a hook to fetch a google sheet, so I need to run the code line by line to see if the hook works. But I can't do that if I keep receiving this db error. I tried `cd` into the directory my file is in and running airflow init db, but I still receive the error..

Comment: Hi @nick_rinaldi I am also facing the similar problem, were you able to resolve this problem? Any help would be appreciable.